# The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression Haskell

Tags: haskell

Based on other similar questions I found I figure my problem has to do with indentation, but I've messed with it a lot and still can't figure it out.

```
addBook = do
    putStrLn "Enter the title of the Book"
    tit <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the author of "++tit
    aut <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the year "++tit++" was published"
    yr <- getLine
```

Comment: this may be relevant to others... I had the first line in the "do" with a tab indent and the rest with spaces :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your case it's not indentation; you really have finished your function with something that is not an expression.  `yr <- getLine` — what did you expect to happen to `yr`, or for that matter `aut`, after this?  They're just dangling, unused.

It may be clearer to show how this translates:

```
addBook = putStrLn "Enter the title of the Book" >>
          getLine >>= \tit ->
          putStrLn "Enter the author of "++ tit >>
          getLine >>= \aut ->
          putStrLn "Enter the year "++tit++" was published" >>
          getLine >>= \yr ->
```

So, what did you want to have following that last arrow?

Comment: Also, you might want to mention that `getLine` can be called without its result being bound, even if that is probably not what he intended.  He might be under the mistaken impression that things with a return type other than `()` must be bound to a variable.

Answer (score 8):

Think about the type of `addBook`. It's `IO a` where `a` is... nothing. That doesn't work. Your monad must have some result.

You might want to add something like this at the end:

```
return (tit, aut, yr)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have any useful result, return an empty tuple (a unit):

```
return ()
```

Comment: @user1319603: Mind you, `return` is unlike its counterparts in imperative languages. In Haskell, `return` is function like any other. It takes a value of some type `a` and wraps it into (in this case) value of type `IO a`. Before you learn about monads it's best to use this rule of thumb: last thing in `do` block must have type `IO a` for some type `a`. In your case, `yr <- getLine` would have type `String` and that's not allowed (indeed, having function of type `IO a → a` breaks lots of nice properties).

Comment: @user1319603 You should *upvote* (click the up arrow for) every answer that helped you, and *accept* (click the check mark for) the answer that is the best or helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

If you take your code:

```
addBook = do
    putStrLn "Enter the title of the Book"
    tit <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the author of "++tit
    aut <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the year "++tit++" was published"
    yr <- getLine
```

and "translate" it to "normal" (non-`do`) notation (given `p = putStrLn "..."`):

```
addBook = 
    p >> getLine >>= (\tit ->
        p >> getLine >>= (\aut ->
            p >> getLine >>= (yr ->
```

You are ending up with `(yr ->` that doesn't make sense. If you don't have anything else useful to do, you can just return an empty tuple:

```
return ()
```

at the end:

```
addBook = do
    putStrLn "Enter the title of the Book"
    tit <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the author of "++tit
    aut <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the year "++tit++" was published"
    yr <- getLine
    return ()
```

You should probably ask yourself why you need to get `aut` and `yr` though.

Comment: +1 for the explicit parentheses!!! ... perhaps `return (tit,aut,yr)` is also appropriate... Also, instead of `yr <- getLine ; return ()` we can just write `getLine` - we choose which depending on what we want to "return".

Answer (score 0):

remove the last line since it's not an expression,
then use parenthesis for the strings you pass to putStrLn.